# Admin 100's of VPS's

Tags: linux, hosting

I have (so far) about 50 VPS's that I have to deploy and have my clients manage thought some sort of control panel.

Initially I thought I'd install ISPConfig 3 on each one of them and use their API to build a custom control panel in PHP, but I then realized it would be overkill: each VPS'S has just 1 website on it, and all I have to do is manage email, FTP, and databases.

What would be a good tool for this? Some super-minimal Webmin, or something like that could perform operations on a remote server...

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree with Kyle Smith, but would also like to add that depending on what virtualization technology it's built on there are are (often a number of) central management tools that are web based.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want this to scale more efficiently than using your web browser one at a time to 100's of VPSes, you need a configuration management tool.  They typically have a decent learning curve, but will allow you to modify many nodes at once and keep things in conformity.

There are many tools to do this, here are the few that come to mind quickly:

- [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com)
- [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/)
- [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com/)

Comment: Awesome, I'll look into those! do they have an API so that I can build a control panel on top of it? Each VPS'S owner would be managing email, etc. but I'd also want to perform some operations on all VPS's at once...

Comment: It might be that you want to use  Puppet to install a control panel for the owners to manage E-Mail, but since it sounds like you're essentially the IT Administrator for the VPSes themselves, you'd also want to have something like Puppet in place.

Answer (score 1):

Something like [Chef](https://github.com/opscode/chef) or [Puppet](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Whos_Using_Puppet)?

Answer (score 0):

[Fabric](http://fabric.readthedocs.org) is an excellent open source project, take a look at following article you'll find a lot of interesting open source project that you can use in your environment: [High Scalability - High Scalability - The Instagram Architecture Facebook Bought for a Cool Billion Dollars](http://bit.ly/JHXpPw)